Azure SQL Insert Failure
Cannot bulk load. The bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table. Sort order incorrect for the following two rows: primary key of first row: (202101, 0xdef2170005000000), primary key of second row: (202102, 0xdef2170005000f00).
I keep getting the above problem on a weekly basis.
In short, we've got a DataFactory pipeline which is running a stored procedure which is inserting data into a fact table for a specific time period. The ADF pipeline runs this stored procedure within a for each loop, where the batch count is set to 10.
At the point the stored procedure does the insert, the fact table is a heap; it has no triggers, indexes, keys, or constraints.
So, can anyone explain why this is happening?

The bulk load error is likely due to incorrect data sort order or concurrency issues. Ensure data is sorted before insertion and handle concurrency by properly partitioning the data and adjusting batch sizes. These steps should mitigate the issue and ensure smooth data insertion into your fact table.
